# asp.net textChanged server side event does not fire

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Our team has developed a large application and now we need to apply capital letters for all text boxes in the system. It is very difficult to do in code behind pages due to the scope of the project. I came up with following jquery and its working fine but problem is once I apply this ,asp.net textChanged server side event does not fire.

```
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $("input:text").not(".textChangedClass").bind("input", function (e) {
            var start = this.selectionStart,
                end = this.selectionEnd;
            this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        });
    }
```

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: Show us your server side code please.

Comment: textChanged event does not fire with above jquery. If i comment above jquery everything will work fine

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will not raise a postback.

I assume you are using ASP.NET web form.

If you need Postback, you should make `AutoPostBack=true` on your server control.

And can you show us how `pageLoad` is called?

Comment: I have used AutoPostBack=true but problem is textChanged event does not fire with above jquery. If i comment above jquery everything works fine

Comment: Why not change the text using the server side code?